# How to SUM coulnms FROM different tables

Tags: sql-server

I am currently working on an established database, i have to produce the reports of the volume of water that has been produced at the same time organize the according to the month then by zones... anyways here's my query

```
*SELECT a.read_month, b.zone, ((SELECT SUM(a.water_used) AS Volume  FROM
[TEST_DB].[dbo].[tblBilling] a) + (SELECT SUM(b.water_used) AS Volume  FROM
[TEST_DB].[dbo].[tblTransaction] b)) AS Volume 
FROM [TEST_DB].[dbo].[tblBilling] a, 
[TEST_DB].[dbo].[tblAccounts] b, 
[TEST_DB].[dbo].[tblTransaction] c 

WHERE a.account_no = b.account_no 
GROUP BY a.read_month, b.zone*
```

and this is the result

```
read_month  zone    Volume
112015       A       460
112015       B       460
112015       C       460
122015       A       460
122015       B       460
122015       C       460
```

it was grouped according to what i intended however the volumes was all the same. this was my idea of the result since account no. 11 and 12 belongs to zone A so their values should be added on zone A and read_month of 112015

```
read_month  zone    Volume
112015       A       80
112015       B       60
112015       C       80
122015       A       60
122015       B       80
122015       C       100
```

these were the tables where the data came from

tblBillings

```
account_no  water_used      read_month
1            20             112015
2            20             112015
3            30             112015
4            30             112015
5            40             112015
6            40             112015
1            30             122015
2            30             122015
3            40             122015
4            40             122015
5            50             122015
6            50             122015
```

tblTransaction

```
account_no  water_used        read_month
11             20               112015
12             20               112015
```

tblAccounts

```
account_no  zone
1            A
2            A
3            B
4            B
5            C
6            C
11           A
12           A
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the query you are looking for:

```
SELECT Temp.read_month, A.zone, SUM(Temp.water_used) 'water_used' FROM
(
    SELECT T.account_no, T.read_month, T.water_used from tblTransaction T
    UNION
    SELECT B.account_no, B.read_month, B.water_used from tblBilling B
) Temp
INNER JOIN tblAccounts A on A.account_no = Temp.account_no
GROUP BY Temp.read_month, a.zone
```

Comment: i tried this one but it didn't really worked the way i wanted to but i could use this for improvement of my query. I haven't tried to make a temp table yet..

Comment: @william Temp is not a Temporary table, its a name to identify records fetched from 2 tables, you can use any name in place of Temp.

Comment: that's what i meant... wrong terms probably... anyways it worked but i was only able to pull one record. i intend to pull all the records like the output that i have posted but this is already a big help...

Comment: Hi kumar... I dont know what just happened... but when i tried this query again today it worked like how i wanted it without doing UNION ALL... Thank you so much for your help...